# override array index operator

Tags: c++, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, operator-overloading

I want to override array index operator in my class. Here's what i am trying to do,but not succeeding.

```
class Complex{              
    Complex const& operator[](unsigned int) const; // Read-only access
    Complex& operator[](unsigned int);             // Read/Write access:
};

const Complex& Complex::operator [](unsigned int unsignedInt) const {
    const Complex* temp = this+i;
    return *temp;
}
Complex& Complex::operator [](unsigned int unsignedInt) {
    Complex* temp = this+i;
    return *temp;
}
```

EDIT : 
I want to do something like :

```
Complex **c = new Complex[5];    //Create 2D array
c[2] = new Complex();            //Initialize
cout<<*c[2];                     //print by overloading <<
```

Comment: What does that do? What's the problem with that code?

Comment: instead of Complex Complex::const& operator[], Complex const Complex::operator[]

Comment: What does it mean: you are not succeeding?

Comment: `Also, in Complex& Complex::operator[]`, you cannot return a pointer as a reference. Return the actual object instead.

Comment: Ouch : `const Complex* temp = this+i;` In short, non-multisyllabic words, **don't do this**.

Comment: What do you want this operator to do? What does it in fact do?

Answer (score 3):

Your function definition syntax is wrong:

```
Complex Complex::const& operator[](unsigned int i) const{
```

The *return type* is supposed to be annotated by `const&`, and the explicit name qualification `Complex::` belongs to the function name, `operator[]`:

```
Complex const& Complex::operator[](unsigned int i) const {
```

Furthermore, the *implementation* seems to be wrong:

```
const Complex* temp = this+i;
return *temp;
```

This doesn’t make a lot of sense. You probably mean something along these lines:

```
Complex temp = *this + i;
return temp;
```

Assuming an appropriate `operator+` overload. Although it’s hard to say which semantics you really want here since there’s no intuitive indexed access for a `Complex` anyway.

Comment: I would like to create an array of pointers i.e. 2D array of Complex class by declaring my own new, delete and [] operaors.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Complex Complex::const& operator[](unsigned int i) const
```

It should be

```
const Complex& Complex::operator[](unsigned int i) const
```